# Finite Difference for Advection Equation With Source

Tags: pde, finite-difference, convergence, stability, advection

I'm trying to find a convergent finite difference scheme for the PDE
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
u_t + (x-1) u_x &= (x-1)u, \hspace{.5cm} x \in [0,1] \\
u(x,0) &= 1 \\
u(1,t) &= 1. \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
I know that the exact solution is $u(x,t) = e^{(x-1)(1-e^{-t})} $, but just wanted some practice working with finite difference schemes. I naively chose the forward-time forward-space with frozen coeeficients discretization \begin{equation}
\frac{u_m^{n+1} - u_m^n}{k} + (x_m-1)\frac{u_{m+1}^n - u_m^n}{h} = (x_m - 1) u_m^n
\end{equation}
since characteristics move from right to left. However, even with $\frac{k}{h} < 1$, the approximate solution is highly unstable. Is this type of discretization insufficient for variable-coefficient advection with a source term? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since $x-1\ge0$, the solution moves to the right, not to the left.  You are using a downwind-biased (and therefore unstable) approximation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The choice of $k$ is restricted also by the discretization of the source term. To see it, rewrite your scheme to
\begin{equation}
u_m^{n+1} = \left(1 - \frac{k(1-x_m)}{h} - k(1-x_m)\right) u_m^n + \frac{k (1-x_m)}{h} u_{m+1}^n \,.
\end{equation}
You need
$$
1 - \frac{k(1-x_m)}{h} - k(1-x_m) \ge 0
$$
for all $x_m$. Taking $x_m=0$ (the worst case scenario) you obtain
$$
1 - \frac{k}{h} - k\ge 0
$$
so your time step $k$ must satisfy
$$
k \le \frac{h}{1 + h} < h
$$
that is more strict then the restriction you write.

If it still does not work for enough small $k$, there should be some implementation problem.

Comment: Thanks!  It actually just turned out to be a typo in my code.